# How to make vertically centered title in markdown

Tags: pandoc, markdown

I have this yaml header in markdown file:

```markdown
---
documentclass: scrartcl
title: Title
author: Author
geometry: "left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm"
output: pdf_document
lang: cs
fontfamily: dejavu
---
```

But the title is not vertically centered (only horizontally) on main page, I want it to be centered vertically and horizontally.

[image: Not Centered]

I tried to add some latex code in yaml

```
title: \vspace{3in}Title
```

But it displays some strange paragraph symbol.

[image: With symbol]

I'm using pandoc with parameter --pdf-engine=xelatex

Comment: I think older version of pandoc or latex did not produce pilcrow symbol when used vspace, I am using archlinux, so I have updated those packages and now it appears.